# Ohai_plugin path can not be determined in chefzero

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

In chef windows  cookbook there is an error in  chef solo mode:

Define a path for the ohai_plugin as path can not be determined.

How to define path explicitly?

Comment: Please be more specific about what error you are seeing.